# Server-Client in One Computer

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, routing

I am starting to learn computer networks. I have some questions about server-client.

1. Is it possible for one computer to be a client and server at the
   same time?I read somewhere you can use XAMPP to do this. I am not
   sure
2. If I have two computers: one with linux mint and one with fedora virtual box, can I create a network via Wifi or do I still need to physically connect to the switch and back panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and yes. Generally. There could be complications depending on your exact set up and software.

Example of 1) On my Windows PC, I've used [Tiny Server](http://tinyserver.sourceforge.net/) to host images. Then a KML file in Google Earth on the same PC refers to those images when I look at certain placemarks. Google Earth normally can't access files on the network, so loading from a local web server is a easy to set up work around. Should work ok on Linux too, so long as you can point your client software to the local host / local IP and the correct port.

Example of 2) If you connect to the router by wifi, it will work as if you are connected by a physical cable (maybe a bit slower on file transfers). If you mean a direct connection without a router, then you'll need an *ad hoc* network and manually assigned IP addresses, but it is still possible.

I can't help you with anything to do with virtual box, or complications that might cause your networking arrangements, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the help. For 1) and 2) Can you tell me the steps on how to do it?

Comment: Set up the server software as per its instructions. It should then be listening for connections on a certain port or range of ports. Then make sure the client software tries to connect on that port to the local IP address. Using my Tinyhost example, I just now started it running as per its instructions to host C:\folder on port 8000, and put an index.html in that folder. typing localhost:8000 into chrome loaded my index.html. I can also access the page via my wireless and cable local IP addresses: http://10.145.50.20:8000/ and http://10.145.50.15:8000/ Same concepts should work in linux.

Comment: for setting up an ad hoc wireless network, you'll need to do your own searches, I haven't done it for ages